# how to do a where-object on an hastable property in powershell?

Tags: powershell, foreach, where-clause

In my foreach I want to do a where-object filter on another object variable.

To be specific, below two instances of my objects array ($arrayCounts) :

```
[0]: [Hastable: 2]
  [0]: [Occurences, 6]
    Key: "Occurences"
    Value: 6
  [1]: [Ip, "10.10.10.10"]
    Key: "Ip"
    Value: "10.10.10.10
[1]: [Hastable: 2]
  [0]: [Occurennces, 3]
    Key: "Occurences"
    Value: 3
  [1]: [Ip, "10.10.10.11"]
    Key: "Ip"
    Value: "10.10.10.11"
```

And here is the loop in which I want to do my where-object :

```
foreach ($result in $resultHash.GetEnumerator()) {
$currentCountResultObject = @{

    Ip         = $result.Key
    Legitimacy = $result.Value
    Occurences = $arrayCounts.Occurences.Value | Where-Object ($result.Key -eq $arrayCounts.Ip.Value)  
    }
    $countResultObject += $currentCountResultObject
}
```

'Ip' and 'Legitimacy' members are well completed but 'Occurences' stays empty because of my wrong where-object expression.

The expected output is :

```
[0]: [Hastable: 3]
  [0]: [Legitimacy, "legitimate"]
    Key: "Legitimacy"
    Value: "legitimate"
  [1]: [Ip, "10.10.10.10"]
    Key: "Ip"
    Value: "10.10.10.10"
  [2]: [Occurences, 3]
    Key: "Occurences"
    Value: 3
[1]: [Hastable: 3]
  [0]: [Legitimacy, "unknown"]
    Key: "Legitimacy"
    Value: "unknown"
  [1]: [Ip, "10.10.10.11"]
    Key: "Ip"
    Value: "10.10.10.11"
  [2]: [Occurences, 28]
    Key: "Occurences"
    Value: 28
```

The aim of the where-object is to give for each IP the number of times it appears and this information is only available in my variable $arrayCounts (outside of my current foreach pipeline).

I hope I am clear enough.

Thanks by advance for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to cross-reference the hashtables in the `$arrayCounts` array by their `Ip` entry values from your `$resultHash` hashtable array.

Based on your code, the `Where-Object` command would need to look as follows:

```
Occurrences = ($arrayCounts | Where-Object { $_.Ip -eq $result.Key }).Occurrences
```

That is, you must enumerate the elements of array `$arrayCounts`, which are hashtables, and check each hashtable's `Ip` entry against the IP address at hand.
The results of this filtering operation is the matching hashtable (I'm assuming that the `Ip` entries are unique across the input hashtables), whose `Occurrences` entry value then contains the desired occurrence count.

Use of the `.Where()` [array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) instead of the `Where-Object` *cmdlet* can speed up the operation, in general, but here also because it allows you to stop filtering once a match is found (argument `'First'`):

```
Occurrences = ($arrayCounts.Where({ $_.Ip -eq $result.Key }, 'First')).Occurrences
```

However, based on the desired output I suspect that your enumeration of your `$resultHash` variable is flawed. Under the assumption that it too is an *array* of hashtables, here's what your code would have to look like:

```
# Array of sample reference hashtables.
$arrayCounts = 
 @{ Occurrences = 6; Ip = "10.10.10.10" },
 @{ Occurrences = 3; Ip = "10.10.10.11" }
 
 # Array of sample result hashtables
 $resultHashes =
   @{ Legitimacy = 'legitimate'; Ip = "10.10.10.10" },
   @{ Legitimacy = 'unknown'; Ip = "10.10.10.11" }

# Loop over the hashtables in $resultHashes, construct a new hashtable
# with the cross-referenced information for each, and collect the
# result in a new hashtable array.
$finalResultHashes = 
  foreach ($resultHash in $resultHashes) {

    # Output a hashtable with that includes the matching Occurrence value
    # from the $arrayCounts array based on this result's IP.
    @{ 
      Ip = $resultHash.Ip
      Legitimacy = $resultHash.Legitimacy
      Occurrences = ($arrayCounts.Where({ $_.Ip -eq $resultHash.Ip }, 'First')).Occurrences
    }

  }

# Output the results for display.
# Note: I'm using JSON only for illustrative purposes.
$finalResultHashes | ConvertTo-Json
```

The above yields (JSON is used merely to clarify the results structure):

```
[
  {
    "Legitimacy": "legitimate",
    "Ip": "10.10.10.10",
    "Occurrences": 6
  },
  {
    "Legitimacy": "unknown",
    "Ip": "10.10.10.11",
    "Occurrences": 3
  }
]
```

Comment: hi mkelement0 and thanks for your help. I was working on another subject but I used your code and change the format of my hashtables and it works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @shako; my pleasure.